# Javascript value isn't being passed while using helper function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion, reference

```
var islandPerimeter = function(grid) {
   let perimeter = 0;

   const dfs = (grid, i, j, perimeter) => {
       grid[i][j] = 2;
       if( i === 0 || grid[i-1][j] === 0) perimeter++;
       if(i === grid.length - 1 || grid[i+1][j] === 0) perimeter++;
       if( j === 0 || grid[i][j-1] === 0) perimeter++;
       if(j === grid[0].length - 1 || grid[i][j+1] === 0) perimeter++;    
       
       if(i > 0 && grid[i-1][j] === 1) dfs(grid, i-1, j, perimeter);
       if(i < grid.length-1 && grid[i+1][j] === 1) dfs(grid, i+1, j, perimeter);
       if(j > 0 && grid[i][j-1] ===1) dfs(grid, i, j-1, perimeter);
       if(j < grid[0].length-1 && grid[i][j+1] === 1) dfs(grid, i, j+1, perimeter); 
       
   }
   
   let r = grid.length;
   let c = grid[0].length;
   
   for(let i = 0; i < r; i++) {
       for(let j = 0; j < c; j++) {
           if(grid[i][j] === 1) {
               dfs(grid, i, j, perimeter);
           }
       }
       return perimeter;
   }
};


const ans = islandPerimeter([
 [0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0]
])
```

I took a C++ answer I found using dfs and converted to javascript... But it won't reference the perimeter value hence returning 0;

How do I fix it and for future reference how does one return value when using a helper function.

Also, another question I have is..

in this question we go through the loop to find the first island, then we dfs the rest. Does that mean the perimeter is answered in one dfs loop or will the for-loop run again... ty

Comment: You should name variables and parameters differently. The `perimeter` in `islandPerimeter` is different than the `perimeter` in `dfs`.

Comment: Just removing the `perimeter` parameter (LOL) from your `dfs` function will fix the problem.  There are probably better JS solutions, though.  It's not that the value is not being passed.  Just the opposite, in fact.  It's that you're passing a copy of a value, manipulating that copy inside `dfs` and the ignoring it when the function returns.

Comment: Can you explain what the program is supposed to do? What is an "island"? What should the output of the program be?

Comment: So the fact I added (perimeter) to the dfs is basically using that instead of the global variable perimeter... that makes sense.

Comment: @Thankyou: this is a fairly classic problem: find the perimeter of an "island" of `1`'s in a grid of `0`'s.  Here's one reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-perimeter-shapes-formed-1s-binary-matrix/ .  This question uses the common solution of marking the visited cells and then calculating the perimeter by finding all neighbors that aren't `1`'s, and recurring on all unvisited neighbors. It starts by finding any `1` available.  If there are multiple islands, it only calculates the one that includes your start cell.  There is a simpler way to total the perimeters of all islands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the minimal change to your code which will fix the problem is to remove `perimeter` as a `parameter` to `dfs`.

But I would like to suggest some improvements.  It will take a few steps to get to where we would like to go.

### Don't modify input data

The first change would be to not modify the grid while processing it.  There are all sorts of good reasons to work with immutable data, especially across function boundaries.  But of course this algorithm is intrinsically about modifying the grid in order to track where you've already visited.  So I would simply pass a *copy* of the data in the original call to the `dfs` function:

```js
dfs (grid .map (row => row .slice (0)), i, j)
```

By calling `map` on the grid, we get a new outer array with the results of the callback to each row.  And by calling `.slice (0)` on each row, we get a copy of the original row.  Together this gives us a new grid with the same data as the original.  (Note that this is still a relatively shallow copy; if the grid elements were objects instead of numbers, they would be shared by reference.)

### Use `return` rather than modifying higher scope variables

Next, `dfs` is modifying a value in a higher scope, the `perimeter`.  This makes it difficult to understand the function.  If instead it returned that value, we could gather the bits together in a more understandable way.  So we could write

```js
  const dfs = (grid, i, j) => {
    grid[i][j] = 2;
    return ((i === 0 || grid[i - 1][j] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
           ((i === grid.length - 1 || grid[i + 1][j] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
           ((j === 0 || grid[i][j - 1] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
           ((j === grid[0].length - 1 || grid[i][j + 1] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +

           ((i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i - 1, j) : 0) +
           ((i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i + 1][j] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i + 1, j) : 0) +
           ((j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i, j - 1) : 0) +
           ((j < grid[0].length - 1 && grid[i][j + 1] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i, j + 1) : 0);
  }
```

We do the same calculations as before, but instead of adding the results to an existing outer-scope variable, we add them together and return them.  That means we can drop the `perimeter` variable altogether and simply return the result of the outer call to `dfs`:

```js
           if(grid[i][j] === 1) {
               return dfs(grid, i, j, perimeter);
           }
```

### Calculate helper variables instead of returning from within a loop

But I find that return from an incomplete `for`-loop quite unsatisfactory.  I would much rather calculate the row and column containing the first `1` and then do a simple `return` using  them.  So I might write something like this:

```js
  const r = grid .findIndex ((row) => row .includes (1));
  const c = grid[r] .findIndex ((col) => col == 1);
  
  return dfs (grid .map (row => row .slice (0)), r, c)
```

### Handle incorrect data gracefully

There is a possible point of failure here.  This code will probably error if the grid has no `1`s in it.  We can avoid that by doing some initial checks on these values, like this:

```js
  const r = grid .findIndex ((row) => row .includes (1));
  const c = r > -1 ? grid[r] .findIndex ((col) => col == 1) : -1;
  
  return (r > -1 && c > -1) ? dfs (grid .map (row => row .slice (0)), r, c) : 0
```

If we find no row with a `1`, then `r` will be `-1`, and we set `c` to `-1` as well.  Then if either one of them is not greater than `-1` we return `0`, carrying on as before in the other case.

### Moving internal function out

But now we can note that `dfs` depends on nothing but its parameters.  It's a pure function, and it no longer has to be embedded in the main function.  Depending on how you package together your functions, you might still want to keep it there.  But if you're using modules, then this could just be a module-private function.  We'll do it that way here.

### Putting it together

We arrive, then, at this version:

```js
const dfs = (grid, i, j) => {
  grid[i][j] = 2;
  return ((i === 0 || grid[i - 1][j] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
         ((i === grid.length - 1 || grid[i + 1][j] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
         ((j === 0 || grid[i][j - 1] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
         ((j === grid[0].length - 1 || grid[i][j + 1] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +

         ((i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i - 1, j) : 0) +
         ((i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i + 1][j] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i + 1, j) : 0) +
         ((j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i, j - 1) : 0) +
         ((j < grid[0].length - 1 && grid[i][j + 1] === 1) ? dfs(grid, i, j + 1) : 0);
}

const islandPerimeter = (grid) => {
  let r = grid .findIndex ((row) => row .includes (1));
  let c = r > -1 ? grid[r] .findIndex ((col) => col == 1) : -1;
  
  return (r > -1 && c > -1) ? dfs (grid .map (row => row .slice (0)), r, c) : 0
};

const grid = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0]
]

console .log (islandPerimeter (grid))
console .log (grid.map(r => r.join(' ')).join('\n'))
```

(We do the second `console.log` statement in order to demonstrate that the initial grid was not modified by our function.)

### Going more purely functional

Functional programming has many tenets, but two of the core ones are to always work with immutable data and to use only pure functions.  We can note that `dfs` breaks both of these.  It mutates the `grid` passed to it, and depends on earlier mutations of that grid to function properly.

There is a serious philosophical question here: If a data structure is modified in a function and there is no code there to observe it, does it make a side-effect?  I would probably leave that function as is because the only things being modified are not visible anywhere except inside the function.  But some purists might disagree.  Here's one way we might satisfy them

We could write a quick helper function that creates a clone of a grid with one of the coordinates updated to `2`, or more generally, updated to an input value.  This is one version:

```js
const setCoord = (grid, x, y, val) => 
  grid .map ((row, r) => r == x ? row.map((col, c) => c == y ? val : col) : row.slice(0))
```

Again we have a somewhat shallow clone of the original, but with the value at `(x, y)` updated to `val`.  We can use this in `dfs` in order to avoid modifying our grid by passing this sort of clone to the recursive calls:

```js
const dfs = (grid, i, j, newGrid = setCoord(grid, i, j, 2)) => 
  ((i === 0 || grid[i - 1][j] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
  ((i === grid.length - 1 || grid[i + 1][j] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
  ((j === 0 || grid[i][j - 1] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +
  ((j === grid[0].length - 1 || grid[i][j + 1] === 0) ? 1 : 0) +

  ((i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] === 1) ? dfs(newGrid, i - 1, j) : 0) +
  ((i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i + 1][j] === 1) ? dfs(newGrid, i + 1, j) : 0) +
  ((j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] === 1) ? dfs(newGrid, i, j - 1) : 0) +
  ((j < grid[0].length - 1 && grid[i][j + 1] === 1) ? dfs(newGrid, i, j + 1) : 0);
```

There is a nice feeling here of working in an entirely pure manner.  And if we wanted to get anal about it, we could also avoid the assignment statements to `r` and `c` in the main function, and then we might even satisfy Haskellers.

But there is a performance disadvantage here is JS.  The previous version does a single clone of the grid; it does this for the legitimate purpose of not modifying the input structure.  Here we need a clone of the entire grid for every block on our island.  For large islands with large grids, this could take a lot of memory, and it will certainly slow down processing speeds.  There are better data structure we could use to reduce these problems, but we cannot eliminate them.  And as our philosopher noted, no one will observe the mutation we're doing anyway.  So I would most likely stick with the previous version.  But it's worth seeing that we can carry this further even in Javascript.

### A simpler algorithm

We could also change the algorithm used.  The algorithm we've been using finds the perimeter of one island, the one which happens to have the most westward extent of all those that have the most northward extents.  In other words, it finds the perimeter of a fairly random island among the islands in the grid.

This is usually swept aside by an assumption that there is only (or at most) one island in the grid.  But if that is the case, then another algorithm is simpler to use: we calculate the total perimeters of *all* islands in the grid.  If there is only one, then we have our answer!

That can be achieved by this simpler code:

```js
const blockPerimeter = (grid, r, c) => 
  ((r == 0 || grid [r - 1] [c] == 0) ? 1 : 0) +                    // top
  ((c == 0 || grid [r] [c + 1] == 0) ? 1 : 0) +                    // right
  ((r == grid .length - 1 || grid [r + 1] [c] == 0) ? 1 : 0) +     // bottom
  ((c == grid [r] .length - 1 || grid [r] [c - 1] == 0) ? 1 : 0)   // left

const islandPerimeter = (grid) => 
  grid .reduce (
    (p, r, i) => r .reduce (
      (p, c, j) => p + (c == 1 ? blockPerimeter (grid, i, j) : 0), 
      p
    ), 
    0
  )
```

Here we just find every `1` in the grid and calculate its contribution to the perimeter by checking its northern, eastern, southern, and western neighbors.  If they are zero (or if we've run off the grid) we add one to our total.

That's it.  That's the entire algorithm.

This is definitely simpler than the above, and if you know there is only one island, this is a useful technique.  But the calculate-and-mark technique above can be extended in a way this one can't.  That one can easily be extended to find the perimeters of *every* island in the grid, by capturing the result for the first `1` found and for the next `1`, etc. until there are no `1`'s remaining.  There is no obvious way to extend this algorithm to do that.

#### Note

We could simplify the core `blockPerimeter` function by wrapping the entire grid in a shell of `0`s.  While that would leave a much nicer version such as

```js
const blockPerimeter = (grid, r, c) => 
  (grid [r - 1] [c] == 0 ? 1 : 0) + // top
  (grid [r] [c + 1] == 0 ? 1 : 0) + // right
  (grid [r + 1] [c] == 0 ? 1 : 0) + // bottom
  (grid [r] [c - 1] == 0 ? 1 : 0)   // left
```

and would even allow us to drop the `? 1 : 0` clauses due to the type coercion caused by the addition (not that I'd ever recommend this!), I think the extra infrastructure needed to wrap the array would make this overall more complex and not worth the time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I loved this

Comment: Updated to add an additional algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to remove the *perimeter* parameter from the *dfs* signature (see code below).

This is because you can't use variables from outside of a functions scope which share the name with a parameter passed to the function - in your case the shared name is *perimeter*.

---

Best to not compound questions on SO, but in terms of the for-loop, **it will complete the necessary computation in the first iteration**, because it is a recursive method. I've tweaked this for you below.

Just to note, you're also returning before the second iteration for the *i* for-loop, so that would cause you problems if it wasn't a recursive method.

---

```js
var islandPerimeter = function(grid) {
  let perimeter = 0;

  const dfs = (grid, i, j) => {
    grid[i][j] = 2;
    if (i === 0 || grid[i - 1][j] === 0) perimeter++;
    if (i === grid.length - 1 || grid[i + 1][j] === 0) perimeter++;
    if (j === 0 || grid[i][j - 1] === 0) perimeter++;
    if (j === grid[0].length - 1 || grid[i][j + 1] === 0) perimeter++;

    if (i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] === 1) dfs(grid, i - 1, j, perimeter);
    if (i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i + 1][j] === 1) dfs(grid, i + 1, j, perimeter);
    if (j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] === 1) dfs(grid, i, j - 1, perimeter);
    if (j < grid[0].length - 1 && grid[i][j + 1] === 1) dfs(grid, i, j + 1, perimeter);

  }

  let r = grid.length;
  let c = grid[0].length;

  dfs(grid, 0, 0, perimeter);
  return perimeter;
};


const ans = islandPerimeter([
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0]
])

console.log(ans);
```

---

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5frao6sg/6/

Comment: I added a snippet.  This is usually cleaner than an external link to something like JSFiddle.

Comment: Note that this doesn't quite work.  You need to search for a `1` first as done in the original.  The easiest way to see this is to duplicate the first row in both this and the (fixed) original.  That one correctly reports 18,  This one would have 20.  You could fix this with something like   `let r = grid .findIndex((row) => row.includes(1)); let c = grid[r] .findIndex((col) => col == 1); dfs(grid, r, c);`.